# R function to see if combinations of multiple vectors match a target vector

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a set of any # of vectors:

```
a<-c("giraffe", "dolphin", "pig")
b<-c("elephant" , "pig")
c<-c("zebra","cobra","spider","porcupine")
d<-c("porcupine")
e<-c("spider","cobra")
f<-c("elephant","pig","porcupine")
```

and a target vector:

```
target<- c("elephant" , "pig","cobra","spider","porcupine")
```

Is there a way to check if any combinations of the vectors can match the target vector (order doesn't matter)?

In this case, answers would be:

- b,d,e
- e,f

Clarifying:
I need to know which combinations exactly match the target vector with no duplicates. Any answers that would repeat a value (e.x. b,d,e,f) would not work.

Comment: check out the [`setdiff`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/prob/versions/1.0-1/topics/setdiff) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions shown in the question consist of non-overlapping vectors so we assume that that is a requirement so that we are looking to partition the target into disjoint vectors that cover it.  If the vectors may overlap then instead of using = or == in the constraints involving A below use >=.

The assumed problem is known as a set partitioning problem and the problem with overlaps is known as a set covering problem.

Assuming the list of vectors L and the target shown in the Note at the end form the objective (all one's), incidence matrix A of vectors, animals and the right hand of the constraint equations `rhs` derived from the target and run the linear program shown.

If a solution is found then we add a constraint that will eliminate it in the next iteration by insisting that at least one of its zeros be one.  We iterate 5 times (i.e. up to 5 solutions) or until we can find no more solutions.

We show a solution using the lpSolveAPI package and then in the section after that repeat it using the CVXR package.

### lpSolveAPI

```
library(lpSolveAPI)

animals <- sort(unique(unlist(L)))
A <- +outer(animals, L, Vectorize(`%in%`))
rownames(A) <- animals
nr <- nrow(A)
nc <- ncol(A)

rhs <- rownames(A) %in% target

lp <- make.lp(nr, nc)
set.objfn(lp, rep(1, nc))
for(i in 1:nr) add.constraint(lp, A[i, ], "=", rhs[i])
for(j in 1:nc) set.type(lp, j, type = "binary")

soln <- solns <- NULL
for(s in 1:5) {
  if (!is.null(soln)) add.constraint(lp, 1-soln, ">=", 1)
  if (solve(lp) != 0) break
  soln <- get.variables(lp)
  solns <- c(solns, list(names(L)[soln == 1]))
}
solns   
## [[1]]
## [1] "e" "f"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "b" "d" "e"
```

### CVXR

An alternative to lpSolve is CVXR.  We use nc, A and rhs from above.  Below we find up to 5 solutions.

```
library(CVXR)

x <- Variable(nc, boolean = TRUE)
objective <- Minimize(sum(x))
constraints <- list(A %*% x == matrix(rhs))

solns <- soln <- NULL
for(i in 1:5) {
  if (!is.null(soln)) constraints <- c(constraints, sum((1 - soln) * x) >= 1)
  prob <- Problem(objective, constraints)
  result <- solve(prob)
  if (result$status != "optimal") break
  soln <- result$getValue(x)
  solns <- c(solns, list(names(L)[soln == 1]))
}
solns
## [[1]]
## [1] "e" "f"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "b" "d" "e"
```

### Note

```
L <- within(list(), {
  a <- c("giraffe", "dolphin", "pig")
  b <- c("elephant" , "pig")
  c <- c("zebra","cobra","spider","porcupine")
  d <- c("porcupine")
  e <- c("spider","cobra")
  f <- c("elephant","pig","porcupine")
})
L <- L[order(names(L))]
target<- c("elephant" , "pig","cobra","spider","porcupine")
```

Comment: Thank you. This found the appropriate solutions given the desire for non-overlapping vectors

Answer (score 1):

By first converting your vectors into a list  `l <- list(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d, e = e, f = f)`

In base R you can use `lapply`:

```
unlist(lapply(l, FUN = function(x) all(x %in% target)))

    a     b     c     d     e     f 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

---

You could accomplish this with the `purrr` library function `imap_lgl`:

```
library(purrr)

purrr::imap_lgl(l, ~ all( . %in% target))
    a     b     c     d     e     f 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If you add a pipe `names` you can get a character vector of the names if you prefer:

```
purrr::imap_lgl(l, ~ all( . %in% target)) %>% 
  names(.)[.]

[1] "b" "d" "e" "f"
```

---

Both of these solutions use `all` and the operator `%in%`. `%in%` works by testing if everything in the LHS vector is in the RHS vector:

```
a %in% target
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

all(a %in% target)
[1] FALSE
```

Since "giraffe" and "dolphin" are not in `target` the first two values return `FALSE` and the last value is `TRUE` since "pig" is in `target`. `all` tests if all values of a vector are `TRUE`. Since not all values of `a` are in `target` it returns `FALSE`.

Comment: This almost works but I need to know which combination of vectors exactly equal the target vector, not just which have values that are in it. In that sense, an answer of b,d,e,f is wrong, because I would end up with 2 pigs, 2 elephants, and 2 porcupines. I need an exact match. I'll clarify in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Build a list with your vectors

   ```r
   vec_list <- list(a, b, c, d, e, f)
   names(vec_list) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
   ```
2. Write a function that identifies matches

   ```
   match_elem <- function(i, the_list, target) {
     if (all( the_list[[i]] %in% target)) {
     return(names(the_list)[[i]])
     }
   }
   ```
3. Apply `match_elem` to each element of the list

   ```r
   unlist(lapply(1:6, match_elem, vec_list, target))

   > "b" "d" "e" "f"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `combn`

```
lst <- list(a, b, c, d, e, f)
nms <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
names(
  Filter(
    isTRUE,
    unlist(
      lapply(
        seq_along(lst),
        function(k) {
          setNames(
            combn(lst, k, FUN = function(v) !(length(setdiff(unlist(v), target)) + length(setdiff(target, unlist(v))))),
            combn(nms, k, toString)
          )
        }
      )
    )
  )
)
```

or

```
subset(
  unlist(
    lapply(
      seq_along(nms), function(k) combn(nms, k, toString)
    )
  ),
  unlist(
    lapply(
      seq_along(lst),
      function(k) combn(lst, k, FUN = function(v) !(length(setdiff(unlist(v), target)) + length(setdiff(target, unlist(v)))))
    )
  )
)
```

gives

```
[1] "e, f"       "b, d, e"    "b, e, f"    "d, e, f"    "b, d, e, f"
```

---

**Update**

If do need to find exclusive combinations, i.e., without overlap, we can try the code below

```
subset(
  unlist(
    lapply(
      seq_along(nms), function(k) combn(nms, k, toString)
    )
  ),
  unlist(
    lapply(
      seq_along(lst),
      function(k) combn(lst, k, FUN = function(v) length(unlist(v))==length(target) & all(unlist(v)%in% target))
    )
  )
)
```

or

```
names(
  Filter(
    isTRUE,
    unlist(
      lapply(
        seq_along(lst),
        function(k) {
          setNames(
            combn(lst, k, FUN = function(v) length(unlist(v))==length(target) & all(unlist(v)%in% target)),
            combn(nms, k, toString)
          )
        }
      )
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
[1] "b, f"    "e, f"    "b, d, e"
```

Comment: This has the same issue as LMC's answer.  b,d,e,f, isn't a solution because there is overlap. This works though if that isn't a concern. I tried to clarify the question

Comment: @Jaycee You didn't mention that you try to avoid overlaps in your post. I have updated my answer so you can check it